# How do install Windows from a Ubuntu machine?

Tags: windows, ubuntu

On my laptop, I have Ubuntu running. Now I want to switch back to Windows Vista. Therefore I inserted my install CD and try to boot from the DVD device, but it seems as if the install CD is not recognized, because booting form DVD device is aborted and the normal Ubuntu is started.

Any hints why this? I don't see an error message, I just notice that it is trying to boot from the DVD device but after a minute or so, Ubuntu is started nevertheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check three other things:

1. Most of the Windows Installation disks require you to "Press any key to boot from CD..."  Are you doing this and can you tell if it is recognizing your keyboard.
2. You say it is trying to boot from the installation device, but can you see anything on the screen pertaining to the actual installation?
3. Some manufacturers of laptops allow you to select the boot device by pushing a key at the right time (e.g. on Dell, you can push `<F2>` to go to Setup or `<F12>` to directly select a boot device.  I would see if your manufacturer does this, and try that as well.

Comment: 1) I don't see any hint like this. All I see is a black screen for maybe one minute and then it boots Ubuntu. 2) No I can't see anything, just black screen 3) I tried both way. Changed the boot order in the BIOS and also try to directly boot from the DVD device. But in both cases I just see a black screen

Comment: What is the Make/Model of the laptop?  Has the BIOS been flashed ever (that you know of)?

Comment: It is an old IBM Thinkpad T43P and no I never flashed the BIOS.

Comment: Can you get into the BIOS setup?

Comment: yes (15chars..)

Comment: Do you have an Ubuntu or some other bootable CD you can try?

Comment: check CD's surface - maybe is too scratchy, also are you able to boot from this CD on different machine

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, have you tried going to the bios and checking if boot from DVD is enabled? Are you sure the install CD is bootable and not damaged?

**EDIT:** have you tried another bootable CD?

Comment: Yes I tried the DVD in another machine and there it works. And i also ensured that it is really the DVD the system tries to boot. I can verify this since it takes really longer than directly booting from the hard disc and I also see that the system tries to access the DVD drive.

Comment: A priori, it is the bios that decides whether you boot from the DVD or the hard disk. I don't think your problem is related to Ubuntu. Reboot and try going to the bios to check if boot from DVD is enabled.

Comment: As I said before it is enabled.

Comment: No, you didn't. You said that you though it was enabled because it taking longer, not that you were sure boot from DVD was enabled in the bios settings.

Comment: Did you solve your issue Rolfcoptr? Have you tried a different bootable CD (such as Ubuntu CD if you have one)?